# Como enviar informações escondidas através de um formulário?

Tags: html, formulário

Eu quero enviar uma informação através de um formulário, contudo não quero que apareça em um campo, ou seja, quero enviar uma informação via post, mas sem que apareça em um `input`. Como fazer isto?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No input, defina o atributo `hidden` e coloque o valor dentro de `value`, assim:

```
<input type="hidden" name="input1" value="valor que você quer passar">
```

Answer (score 1):

Talvez não seja seu caso, mas se você estiver fazendo isso para implementar a técnica do [honeypot](https://solutionfactor.net/blog/2014/02/01/honeypot-technique-fast-easy-spam-prevention/), onde você coloca um campo hidden para identificar que seu usuário é na verdade um bot spammer, um `input type="hidden"` não seria a melhor forma, visto que é trivial para um bot identificar que esse campo não deve ser preenchido.

Outras formas de fazer isso são:

- em JavaScript:

  ```
  document.querySelector('input[name="NAME"]')[0].style.visibility = 'hidden';
  ```

  ou

  ```
  document.querySelector('input[name="NAME"]')[0].style.display = 'none';
  ```
- em jQuery:

  ```
  $('input[name="NAME"]').hide();
  ```
- em CSS:

  ```
  input[name="NAME"] {
      display: none;
  }
  ```

Sim, um bot que possua um parser de JavaScript e CSS também conseguirá identificar que o input não deve ser preenchido, mas o método acima já impede que bots simples não spammem seu site.